# How to delete a class member pointer of the class type inside the class

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory

I have a piece of code like the following:

```
class Base {
 public:
  Base(){}
  Base(int in);

  virtual ~Base() { delete b_; }

 private:
  Base *b_;
  int in_;
};

class Derived : public Base {
 public:
  Derived(){}
  ~Derived() {}
};

Base::Base(int i) : in_(in){
  b_ = new Derived();
}

int main() {
  Base *b = new Base(1);
  delete b; 
  return 0;
}
```

I got segmentation fault when deleting b_ inside Base, and I guess the reason is because that it would end up in infinite recursive calls to ~Base(). I also tried to call ~Derived() in main() and then delete b, but there's still memory leak since b_ is not freed.

So my question is what is the right way to free all the memory if I have code like this. I've searched for a solution for hours without getting any satisfying results. So any suggestions would help, thanks.

Comment: why would a base type know something about the derived type?

Comment: Every `Derived` owns another `Derived`.  That can't possibly work.

Comment: @codekaizer Thanks for pointing out, I've made it a bit clearer. The code is abstracted from a rather complicated system. And it's designed as such simply because the system requires it so. And why it has this requirement is quite off the current topic...

Comment: I might note that part of the problem is that you have a virtual destructor `~Base()` which is overridden by the non-virtual `~Derived()`. I'm amazed that's even allowed, to be honest.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo - the base class destructor is virtual, so the derived class destructor is as well.

Comment: Huh. Okay. Guess I've never tried doing that myself. I just kind of assumed `virtual` was necessary in the derived version. My bad :/

Comment: The code, as shown, does not provide enough information to allow the symptom to be recreated.   Read up on how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: There must be other code we're not seeing here which must not initialize b_ in this way in the case where it is inside a derived class. Otherwise the constructor will recurse indefinitely.

Consider what's happening here:

You call the base class constructor to initialize b_ with a new derived instance from the heap. The new derived instance also calls the base class constructor to initialize its (separate) inherited b_ with another derived class, and so on.

Comment: *"I got segmentation fault when deleting b_ inside Base"* - How did you surmise that? Did you manage to step in there with a debugger? Because the code you show would cause a segmentation fault long before any destructor is called.

Answer (score -2):

Adding another function in the Base class which does

```
delete b_;
```

and calling it in main() before destructing b solves the problem.

EDIT:

After half a day's work, I finally come to the following conclusions:

1. The code posted in the question compiles and runs with GCC, but it gives me segmentation fault if I compile it using mac's integrated compiler (clang) and then run.
2. The reason of 1. is deleting `b_` inside the `~Base()` is a recursive call and will end up deleting an uninitialized pointer (some uninitialized `b_`) at some point. If compiling with GCC, the compiler (or at least my compiler) initializes `b_` to `nullptr` (I know that according to c++ standards, the default value of `b_` is undefined), and that's why the program ends normally. But with clang, `b_` is not given any specific default value by the compiler, so I got segmentation fault.
3. A workaround is to set `b_` to `nullptr` by default (in the default constructor of `Base`) and add something like this inside `~Base()`: `if (b_ != nullptr) delete b_;`

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. It makes the symptoms go away.